# Returning a value borrowed from inside a closure

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm looking to get a `Vec<&Metadata>` from `files`:

```
use std::fs::File;

fn example(files: Vec<&File>) {
    let files_metadata: Vec<_> = files
        .iter()
        .map(|f| &f.metadata().unwrap())
        .collect();
}
```

A temporary value is created and dropped in the `map`, it needs to live as long as `files_metadata`.

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:39
  |
6 |         .map(|f| &f.metadata().unwrap())
  |                   --------------------^
  |                   |                   |
  |                   |                   temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
  |                   temporary value created here
7 |         .collect();
8 | }
  | - temporary value needs to live until here
```

Comment: *A temporary value is created and dropped in the map*; yes, that's right... so **don't do that**. `.map(|f| f.metadata().unwrap())` instead. If you *truly* need a `Vec[&Metadata]`, you will need to build it based on the intermediate `Vec<Metadata>`. Otherwise, you'd have references to invalid memory.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, that allowed me to fix it